# Access Permissions of Files -Salesforce and Share Point integration

Tags: integration, security, files, sharepoint, files-connect

We're exploring option to build integration between Salesforce and Share Point. We're looking into various options like File Connect or appExchange tools but we're getting stuck at one important point- which is Security. We're yet to find any option which can meet below requirement

Our Requirement is simple-  if record is private then files attached to it(related list) should be private. If files are stored in Salesforce, it is taken care off automatically- if you don't have access to record, you can't access file.

But if we send the files to Sharepoint, how this will be done ?

In other words, if suppose OWD is private and if record is shared by sharing rules(manual/automatic/apex) with few users . then **'only those set of users'** should have access to Files in Sharepoint.

Please Let me know if some one has done any work or has any idea how this requirement can be fulfilled.

- Are there any APIs available ?
- Any Managed package which can set the permissions at share point end accordingly ?
- or this can **only be** managed **manually** at Share point end ?(which will be tricky that will include  finding all the users who has access to record in Salesforce first and then manually giving them access at share point)